# Sliding Tabs - Android

Tags: android, json, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm creating some kind of horoscope. I have one fragment with all horoscope signs, so when user click on one horoscope sign, I'm sending that sign name to the web service and I'm getting JSON with horoscope content for that sign. This content is split in 4 parts: daily, weekly, monthly and yearly. For that I'm creating 4 tabs and filing with content from JSON.
But the problem is when I go back to all horoscope signs, the 4 tabs are still there. I don't want tabs to be shown. So I need somehow to hide that 4 tabs, and show them again when user click on another (or the same) horoscope sign. Also when I click on another sign the 4 new tabs are created, but with the old passed sign, not with new. And sometimes the whole screen is white, there is not content. Here is my whole code:

**FragmentHoroscopePage.java** (The fragment with all horoscope signs):

```
public class FragmentHoroscopePage extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private FragmentItemHoroscopePage itemHoroscope;
    private FragmentManager manager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_horoscope, container, false);
        Log.d("FRAGMENT", "FragmentHoroscope");

        manager = getFragmentManager();

        ImageView ivOven = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivOven);
        ImageView ivBik = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBik);
        ImageView ivBliznaci = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBliznaci);

        ImageView ivRak = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivRak);
        ImageView ivLav = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivLav);
        ImageView ivDevica = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivDevica);

        ImageView ivVaga = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivVaga);
        ImageView ivSkorpija = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivSkorpija);
        ImageView ivStrelec = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivStrelec);

        ImageView ivJarec = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivJarec);
        ImageView ivVodolija = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivVodolija);
        ImageView ivRibi = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivRibi);

        ivOven.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivBik.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivBliznaci.setOnClickListener(this);

        ivRak.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivLav.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivDevica.setOnClickListener(this);

        ivVaga.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivSkorpija.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivStrelec.setOnClickListener(this);

        ivJarec.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivVodolija.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivRibi.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        itemHoroscope = new FragmentItemHoroscopePage();
        transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String sign = null;

        switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.ivOven:
            sign = "oven";
            break;
        case R.id.ivBik:
            sign = "bik";
            break;
        case R.id.ivBliznaci:
            sign = "bliznaci";
            break;

        case R.id.ivRak:
            sign = "rak";
            break;
        case R.id.ivLav:
            sign = "lav";
            break;
        case R.id.ivDevica:
            sign = "devica";
            break;

        case R.id.ivVaga:
            sign = "vaga";
            break;
        case R.id.ivSkorpija:
            sign = "skorpija";
            break;
        case R.id.ivStrelec:
            sign = "strelec";
            break;

        case R.id.ivJarec:
            sign = "jarec";
            break;
        case R.id.ivVodolija:
            sign = "vodilija";
            break;
        case R.id.ivRibi:
            sign = "ribi";
            break;
        }

        bundle.putString("horoscope_sign", sign);
        itemHoroscope.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, itemHoroscope, "ItemHoroscopePage");
        transaction.addToBackStack("ItemHoroscopePage");
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**FragmentItemHoroscopePage.java** - Here I'm creating 4 tabs, the ViewPager and adapter

```
public class FragmentItemHoroscopePage extends Fragment implements TabListener {

    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private String sign;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_horoscope, container, false);
        Log.d("FRAGMENT", "FragmentItemHoroscope");

        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

        sign = getArguments().getString("horoscope_sign");

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(manager));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float from, int pix) { }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) { }
        });

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.dneven).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.nedelen).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.mesecen).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.godisen).setTabListener(this));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("horoscope_sign", sign);
            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FragmentDaily();
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = new FragmentWeekly();
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment = new FragmentMonthly();
                break;

            case 3:
                fragment = new FragmentYearly();
                break;
            }

            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() { return 4; }
    }
}
```

**FragmentDaily.java** - One of the four tabs, others all the same, but with different content. Here I'm getting the passed horoscope_sign and in AsyncTask I'm sending POST request to web service, and get JSON. When task is done, I'm creating content of first tab (tab Daily)

```
public class FragmentDaily extends Fragment {

    private Context context;
    private ItemDaily itemDaily;

    private ImageView ivZnak;
    private TextView tvZnak;
    private TextView tvDay;
    private TextView tvText;

    private FragmentManager manager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private FragmentItemHoroscopePage itemHoroscopePage;

    private List<NameValuePair> pair;
    private String horoscope_sign;

    private String[] znak = new String[12];

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dneven, container, false);
        Log.d("HOROSCOPE FRAGMENT", "FragmentDaily");

        context = getActivity();
        manager = getFragmentManager();
        bundle = new Bundle();
        itemHoroscopePage = new FragmentItemHoroscopePage();

        znak = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.horoscope);

        horoscope_sign = getArguments().getString("horoscope_sign");
        pair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("horoscope_sign", horoscope_sign));

        System.out.println("UNUTRA" + horoscope_sign);

        new GetHoroscopeTask().execute();

        ivZnak = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivDailyZnak);
        tvZnak = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDailyZnak);

        tvDay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDailyDay);
        tvText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDailyText);

        return view;
    }

    class GetHoroscopeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait, Colecting data!");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Variables.URL_HOROSCOPE);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                    itemDaily = new ItemDaily();

                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONObject jRealObject = jObject.getJSONObject("daily");

                    itemDaily.setText(jRealObject.getString("text").toString());
                    itemDaily.setDay(jRealObject.getString("day").toString());

                    return true;

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, Variables.ERROR_MESSAGE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            if(result == false) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Variables.ERROR_MESSAGE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if(dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                tvDay.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.dneven_horoskop) + " " + itemDaily.getDay());
                tvText.setText(Html.fromHtml(itemDaily.getText()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new intent then. Just dont do finish(); in the tab activity. If ever you wish to go to the tabs again just call finish();

Comment: But I'm using fragments, not activities

Comment: a fragment can still call intent, but if you really don't want to use a normal activity, Then maybe you should do a navigation drawer for the horoscopes.